# Angular4 website - How to export it to APK

Tags: android, angular, ionic3

I've cloned an [Angular 4 demo project](https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app) from github and could run it perfectly in my localhost's browser

What I want to do now, is to create an APK (just the `APK`, not IPA) for displaying that same website through an app.

As far as I understand, there are several options:

- To use `Ionic 3`
- To use `NativeScript`
- To use `Cordova`
- Other options?

I'm trying now the 1st option, creating an empty `Ionic 3` project. 
But now, what are the next steps?

In the `Ionic 3` empty project I can see several folders: `app`, `src`, `plugins`, etc...
The `Angular 4` folder has all the code inside `src` folder.

Should I just copy the `Angular 4` `src` folder into the Ionic project and that's all?

What about the complexity of any other alternative (`NativeScript` , etc...)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no u can't just copy paste. You need to change the code as ionic uses different routing and even html as some tags are also different

Comment: angular src will not work in ionic.

Comment: thanks guys! and then what is your advice? To migrate the website to Ionic3 so with same shared code I'll have the website and the APK available?

Comment: you can host your website somewhere and then create an android application at the main activity put a `WebView` and load the website url then generate the apk.

Comment: I suggest the cordova. Create a new cordova project with cordova cli https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/ and copy your angular 4 project build to the cordova www folder and build cordova. You may need some little changes on your angular project but maybe this is the easier way to reach your goal.